# Extract labels from tflite model file

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a trained TF-Lite model (model.tflite) for image classification with several labels. The output of the model provides an array of probabilities, but I don't know the order to the labels.

Can I extract the labels from the TF model?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do is to dump the labels file from the TF Lite model file. That file is a zip archive, so just do this:

```
unzip mobilenet_v1_0.75_160_quantized_1_metadata_1.tflite
Archive:  mobilenet_v1_0.75_160_quantized_1_metadata_1.tflite
  extracting: labels.txt
```

The "labels.txt" file (or something similarly named) contains the list of labels for the model.

Reference (and more info on how to read TF Lite model metadata): https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/convert/metadata#read_the_associated_files_from_models

**Note:** A TF Lite model is not guaranteed to contain a labels file like this, but most publicly published models, such as ones on tfhub.dev, should have this metadata included.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might extract the metadata

```
pip install tflite_support
import os
from tflite_support import metadata as _metadata
from tflite_support import metadata_schema_py_generated as _metadata_fb
model_file = <model_path>
displayer = _metadata.MetadataDisplayer.with_model_file(model_file)
export_json_file = os.path.join(os.path.splitext(model_file)[0] + ".json")
json_file = displayer.get_metadata_json()
with open(export_json_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(json_file)
```

Comment: This instruction does get metadata from the TF Lite model, but doesn't actually give you a listing of labels.